# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'maimana\App' not found -- slim3

Tags: php, slim, autoload

i was following alex's [how to build a shopping cart lesson](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GL5pG1Sx-oc) and everything's working fine. but then i dont know what im doing wrong so i get this error :

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'maimana\App' not found in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/maimana/bootstrap/app.php:13 Stack trace: #0 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/maimana/public/index.php(3): require() #1 {main} thrown in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/maimana/bootstrap/app.php on line 13
```

bootsrap/app.php :

```
<?php

use Respect\Validation\Validator as v;
 use maimana\App as MyApp;
 use Slim\Views\Twig;
 use Illuminate\Database\Capsule\Manager as Capsule;


 session_start();

 require __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';

 $app = new MyApp;

 $container = $app->getContainer();


 $capsule = new Capsule;

 $capsule->addConnection([
   'driver' => 'mysql',
   'host' => 'localhost',
   'database' => 'maimana',
   'username' => 'rdp46',
   'password' => 'littlelion4696',
   'charset' => 'utf8',
   'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
   'prefix' => ''
 ]);
 $capsule->setAsGlobal();
 $capsule->bootEloquent();

 require __DIR__ . '/../app/routes.php';
```

Myapp/App.php :

```
   namespace maimana;

 use DI\ContainerBuilder;
 use DI\Bridge\Slim\App as DiBridge;

 class App extends DiBridge{
   protected function configureContainer(ContainerBuilder $builder)
   {
     $builder->addDefinitions([
       'settings.displayErrorDetails' => true,
     ]);

     $builder->addDefinitions(__DIR__ . '/container.php');
   }     
 }
```

anyone know what's going on?

Comment: read this [psr4](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/) to autoload your class

Comment: I did but nothing changed

Comment: May we see your `composer.json`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rename the `Myapp` directory to `maimana` (note case) and then update your `composer.json` to autoload the `maimana` namespace.

i.e. ensure that your composer.json has:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "maimana\\": "maimana/"
     }
}
```

This assumes that the `maimana` directoryis in the root of your project where the `composer.json` file is. Once you have changed `composer.json`, you need to run `composer dumpautoload` for the changes to take effect.

This is required because there is a one to one mapping between directory name that the PHP file is in and the namespace for the class in that PHP file. As the namespace in your `App.php` is `maimana`, the directory needs to be `maimana`.